# How to bind to a specific item inside a parent Collection MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, xaml, mvvm

I am making an MVVM WPF program and want to bind a childgrid to a single item in a parent collection, I am using telerik (RadGridView).

The situation is as follows:

```
public class ItemDetails
{
    Item item {get; set;}
    string version {get; set;}
}

public class Item
{
    ObservableCollection<ItemVersion> itemVersions { get; set;}
}

public class ItemVersion
{
    string version {get; set;}
    ObservableCollection<ItemVersionSubItemVersion> subItemVersions {get; set;}
}

public class ItemVersionSubItemVersion
{
    ItemVersion parentItemVersion {get; set;}
    ItemVersion subItemVersion {get; set;}
}
```

I bind an ObservableCollection< ItemDetails> to my RadGridView and depending on what Version is requested in ItemDetails, I want to show all SubItemVersion members of the ItemVersion with that correct Version (Version will allways be unique and if there is none available a new ItemVersion will be created with an empty ObservableCollection< SubItems>).

The only way I got this semi-working was by first showing all ItemVersions in Item and then going to the SubItems, but this shows irrelevant ItemVersions aswell and not just the one I need. So I want to skip a link in the chain, so to speak, and go straight to the SubItemVersions.

I was wondering if anyone knew how to either be able to select a certain item from a collection in xaml, somewhat like a linq query, but in xaml, or some other way to directly go to the SubItemVersions of the right ItemVersion.

A few requirements and ideas I had that made it difficult for me to come up with a solution myself:

- The whole thing needs to stay in one view, so the user can keep a good overview of the structure (a SubItemVersion can have SubItemVersions of its own, which can get messy rather quickly).
- It needs to be MVVM, so it would be best if the code behind of the view is avoided, pure xaml is strongly preferred.
- I would prefer if the models do not need to be changed, but, if no other solution is available, I will have no other choice but to do so.
- I thought of changing the following:

  ```
  public class ItemDetails
  {
      Item item {get; set;}
      string version {get; set;}
  }
  ```

  to:

  ```
  public class ItemDetails
  {
      Item item {get; set;}
      ItemVersion version {get; set;}
  }
  ```

  But this would add an ItemVersion that is already in the ItemVersions collection in Item, so I am generating more (duplicate) data than necessary, correct? Or is this, in fact, a proper solution?

Any idea or input is welcome and greatly appreciated and if you need more information, please let me know so I can try and provide it.

EDIT:
I solved my problem by creating a new ViewModel which contains

```
ItemVersion version
ItemDetails details
```

And created a collection of this new class to bind to the details, where version returns the right version, taken from details. This seemed like the best solution and quite simple to achieve.

Comment: Can you share some xaml? Also introducing a variable in your ViewModel which you want to show might help

Comment: Thanks for the help @lokusking I figured it out eventually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by creating a new ViewModel which contains

```
ItemVersion version
ItemDetails details
```

And created a collection of this new class to bind to the details and version, where version returns the right version taken from details. This seemed like the best solution and quite simple to achieve.